# Get submission ID ninja forms

Tags: forms, wordpress

I need to grab the submission ID of a form that is being processed. Does anyone know how to do this during ninja_forms_post_process?

I've tries using $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value and seeing if it was stored there but it doesn't seem to be which makes sense since it's not form field.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed their great support and here's the answer:

```
$ninja_forms_processing->get_form_setting( 'sub_id' )
```

Comment: Could you explain where exactly put this code in wordpress admin page? and my theme has options.php should I create the function there?

Answer (score 2):

The `sub_id` doesn't populate until `ninja_forms_post_process` at priority 10, so you need to use something like the below to get the ID of the current submission:

```
add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', function () {
    global $ninja_forms_processing;
    var_dump( $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_setting( 'sub_id' ) );
}, 11 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply grab the form id which is submitted either you have one or more ninja forms Go to functions.php in wordpress theme(active theme) ,you must include

> global $ninja_forms_processing;

in order to access the things in ninja forms here is all code for it

```
add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', function () {
  global $ninja_forms_processing;
  $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();

    echo $form_id;(you will get the form id which is submitted)

}
```